# Need Magento 2 - My Account Menu Help

Tags: magento-2.2.1

images/logo.png
          
        
        
          
          
        
        
        
        
        
        
      
    
    
    
      
      
        
          navigation-sections
          nav-sections
        
      
    
    
      
        
        
        
          
          
        
        
      
    
    
      
        
          
            
              
                links
              
            
          
          
        
      
    
    
      
        
      
    
    
      
        
          Privacy Policy
          privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode

Comment: whether your issue is solved if not mention the details

Comment: No, it is not yet resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add this section in default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="mycart.link" after="wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">My Cart</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">checkout/cart</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">my-cart-link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```